# Remove value from entitycollection

Tags: c#, entity, entitycollection

I need to remove the Entity from the entitycollection based on some values.

```
EntityCollection users = new EntityCollection();

List<string> UsersList = new List<string>();
UsersList.add("test1")
UsersList.add("test2")
UsersList.add("test3")


foreach (string item in UsersList )
                {
                    string ls = item;
                   // here I need to remove the users (entitycollection) value based on ls
                }
```

Comment: I think you should execute it as a query, since doing so required iteration for each entity.

Comment: foreach (string item in UsersList )
                    {
                        string ls = item;
        
                       // here I need to remove the users (entitycollection) value based on ls
                       var refer = users.Entities.References.FirstOrDefault(r => r.value == ls);
                    }

Comment: If i use the for each state means am getting the following error,'DataCollection<Entity>' does not contain a definition for 'References' and no extension method 'References' accepting a first argument of type 'DataCollection<Entity>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class User
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

EntityCollection<User> users = new EntityCollection<User>();
        users.Add(new User() { Name = "test1" });

        List<string> UsersList = new List<string>();
        UsersList.Add("test1");
        UsersList.Add("test2");
        UsersList.Add("test3");


        foreach (string item in UsersList)
        {
            string ls = item;
            var user = users.Where(x => x.Name == ls).FirstOrDefault();
            if(user!=null)
                users.Remove(user); 
        }
```